# Trouble with quotes in JSON object to write to the database

Tags: java, javascript, json

I currently have a case where I want to record a JSON object in the bank to get it back and when you want it
this object is manipulated by the JavaScript object JSON

But I'm having a problem that I never had when I record quotes in a String object and try to save the bank quotes lose it impossible to escape String becoming again in a json object.

In practice :
JSON string that is sent:

```
 {"footer":"this is a double quote \"","header":""}
```

String that writes to the database :

```
 {"footer":"this is a double quote "","header":""}
```

So the error to pass JSON back.

In the code :

```
// My SQL
String sql = "UPDATE table SET val='%s' WHERE 1";

// The JSON string to be recorded ( This value comes within a variable (not literal ) )
String jsonString = // {"footer":"this is a double quote \"","header":""};

// Create statement in JDBC
con.prepareStatement(String.format(sql, jsonString)).execute();

// The following SQL statement generates the toString() ;
UPDATE table SET val='{"footer":"this is a double quote \"","header":""}' WHERE 1

// In the database the following String is recorded
{"footer":"this is a double quote "","header":""}
```

My table is set up like this:
utf8
utf8_general_ci

[image]

Why this happening and what can I do to solve this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: [You need to escape the backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034385/how-do-i-escape-backslashes-in-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use prepared statements:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Example Snippet:

```
PreparedStatement statement = null;
String sql = "UPDATE table SET val=? WHERE 1";

statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(1, jsonString);
statement.executeUpdate();
con.commit();
```